Vercel deployment / Turborepo - Build always fails until manually rebuilt while disabling cache. Internal packages not found
I've tried to summarise as best I can. Effectively, every time I deploy and Vercel builds, the build fails citing that the internal packages can't be found.
If I manually redeploy and select the option to disable the cache, this then works fine. I've tried adding the environment variable to the Vercel deployment to disable the Turbo cache on build. I've done this with a key of VERCEL_FORCE_NO_BUILD_CACHE and a value of 1.
Build logs below. Any help would be greatly appreciated:
[18:56:07.701] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[18:56:07.873] Cloning github.com/myaccount/testapp (Branch: main, Commit: 6e6b01d)
[18:56:07.912] VERCEL_FORCE_NO_BUILD_CACHE is set so skipping build cache step
[18:56:08.859] Cloning completed: 987.877ms
[18:56:09.373] Running "vercel build"
[18:56:09.792] Vercel CLI 37.9.0
[18:56:09.973] > Detected Turbo. Adjusting default settings...
[18:56:10.354] Detected `pnpm-lock.yaml` version 9 generated by pnpm@9.x
[18:56:10.359] Running "install" command: `pnpm install`...
[18:56:11.717] Scope: all 11 workspace projects
[18:56:12.000] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
[18:56:12.242] ../..                                    |    +1075 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[18:56:13.007] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 29, added 20
[18:56:14.009] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 59, added 45
[18:56:15.010] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 89, added 74
[18:56:16.023] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 155, added 145
[18:56:17.065] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 169, added 155
[18:56:18.070] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 171, added 158
[18:56:19.071] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 183, added 169
[18:56:20.073] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 184, added 169
[18:56:21.075] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 185, added 169
[18:56:22.076] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 191, added 177
[18:56:23.078] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 199, added 186
[18:56:24.081] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 211, added 199
[18:56:25.082] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 313, added 305
[18:56:26.083] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 382, added 380
[18:56:27.089] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 474, added 469
[18:56:28.085] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 508, added 510
[18:56:29.085] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 622, added 621
[18:56:30.085] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 719, added 714
[18:56:31.101] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 740, added 736
[18:56:32.110] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 790, added 782
[18:56:33.127] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 841, added 836
[18:56:34.127] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 858, added 851
[18:56:35.128] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 861, added 851
[18:56:36.129] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 862, added 851
[18:56:37.130] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 877, added 867
[18:56:38.133] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 950, added 946
[18:56:39.134] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 966, added 956
[18:56:40.134] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 975, added 966
[18:56:41.135] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 1058, added 1052
[18:56:41.992] ../..                                    | Progress: resolved 1075, reused 0, downloaded 1069, added 1075, done
[18:56:42.616] .../es5-ext@0.10.64/node_modules/es5-ext postinstall$  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
[18:56:42.617] .../node_modules/@swc/core postinstall$ node postinstall.js
[18:56:42.618] .../node_modules/@clerk/shared postinstall$ node ./scripts/postinstall.mjs
[18:56:42.681] .../sharp@0.33.4/node_modules/sharp install$ node install/check
[18:56:42.709] .../esbuild@0.23.0/node_modules/esbuild postinstall$ node install.js
[18:56:42.771] .../node_modules/@swc/core postinstall: Done
[18:56:42.801] .../esbuild@0.19.12/node_modules/esbuild postinstall$ node install.js
[18:56:42.851] .../es5-ext@0.10.64/node_modules/es5-ext postinstall: Done
[18:56:42.961] .../esbuild@0.23.0/node_modules/esbuild postinstall: Done
[18:56:42.995] .../node_modules/@clerk/shared postinstall: Done
[18:56:43.022] .../node_modules/core-js-pure postinstall$ node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
[18:56:43.107] .../esbuild@0.19.12/node_modules/esbuild postinstall: Done
[18:56:43.129] .../node_modules/core-js-pure postinstall: Done
[18:56:43.174] .../sharp@0.33.4/node_modules/sharp install: Done
[18:56:43.973] 
[18:56:43.973] dependencies:
[18:56:43.973] + @clerk/nextjs 5.6.0
[18:56:43.973] + @testapp/i18n 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/i18n
[18:56:43.978] + @testapp/theme 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/theme
[18:56:43.978] + @testapp/ui 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/ui
[18:56:43.978] + @testapp/utils 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/utils
[18:56:43.981] + class-variance-authority 0.7.0
[18:56:43.981] + framer-motion 11.0.28
[18:56:43.981] + lucide-react 0.427.0
[18:56:43.981] + next 14.2.13
[18:56:43.982] + next-intl 3.15.0
[18:56:43.982] + next-themes 0.3.0
[18:56:43.982] + react 18.3.1
[18:56:43.982] + react-dom 18.3.1
[18:56:43.982] + react-wrap-balancer 1.1.0
[18:56:43.982] + sharp 0.33.4
[18:56:43.983] 
[18:56:43.983] devDependencies:
[18:56:43.983] + @next/eslint-plugin-next 14.1.4
[18:56:43.983] + @types/eslint 8.56.8
[18:56:43.983] + @types/node 20.12.7
[18:56:43.983] + @types/react 18.3.3
[18:56:43.983] + @types/react-dom 18.3.0
[18:56:43.984] + @testapp/eslint-config 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/eslint-config
[18:56:43.984] + @testapp/tailwind-config 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/tailwind-config
[18:56:43.984] + @testapp/typescript-config 0.0.0 <- ../../packages/typescript-config
[18:56:43.984] + autoprefixer 10.4.19
[18:56:43.984] + eslint 8.57.0
[18:56:43.984] + eslint-config-next 14.2.13
[18:56:43.985] + postcss 8.4.38
[18:56:43.985] + tailwindcss 3.4.4
[18:56:43.985] + typescript 5.4.5
[18:56:43.985] 
[18:56:44.062] Done in 33.6s
[18:56:44.120] Detected Next.js version: 14.2.13
[18:56:44.121] Running "turbo run build"
[18:56:44.351] 
[18:56:44.351] Attention:
[18:56:44.351] Turborepo now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[18:56:44.351] This information is used to shape the Turborepo roadmap and prioritize features.
[18:56:44.351] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[18:56:44.351] https://turbo.build/repo/docs/telemetry
[18:56:44.351] 
[18:56:44.418] • Packages in scope: web
[18:56:44.419] • Running build in 1 packages
[18:56:44.419] • Remote caching enabled
[18:56:44.681] @testapp/utils:build: cache hit, replaying logs eb37e7af2d3f0722
[18:56:44.681] @testapp/utils:build: 
[18:56:44.682] @testapp/utils:build: > @testapp/utils@0.0.0 build /vercel/path0/packages/utils
[18:56:44.682] @testapp/utils:build: > tsup
[18:56:44.682] @testapp/utils:build: 
[18:56:44.682] @testapp/utils:build: CLI Building entry: src/index.ts, src/functions/index.ts, src/functions/utils.ts
[18:56:44.682] @testapp/utils:build: CLI Using tsconfig: tsconfig.json
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: CLI tsup v8.0.2
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: CLI Using tsup config: /vercel/path0/packages/utils/tsup.config.ts
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: CLI Target: es6
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: ESM Build start
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: ESM dist/index.mjs           87.00 B
[18:56:44.683] @testapp/utils:build: ESM dist/functions/index.mjs 84.00 B
[18:56:44.684] @testapp/utils:build: ESM dist/chunk-UFTVL56S.mjs  0 B
[18:56:44.684] @testapp/utils:build: ESM dist/functions/utils.mjs 54.00 B
[18:56:44.684] @testapp/utils:build: ESM dist/chunk-TJENTO3V.mjs  117.00 B
[18:56:44.684] @testapp/utils:build: ESM ⚡️ Build success in 17ms
[18:56:44.684] @testapp/utils:build: DTS Build start
[18:56:44.685] @testapp/utils:build: DTS ⚡️ Build success in 2590ms
[18:56:44.685] @testapp/utils:build: DTS dist/functions/utils.d.mts 106.00 B
[18:56:44.685] @testapp/utils:build: DTS dist/functions/index.d.mts 49.00 B
[18:56:44.685] @testapp/utils:build: DTS dist/index.d.mts           59.00 B
[18:56:44.864] @testapp/ui:build: cache hit, replaying logs 91f60e740a078900
[18:56:44.864] @testapp/ui:build: 
[18:56:44.864] @testapp/ui:build: > @testapp/ui@0.0.0 build /vercel/path0/packages/ui
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: > tsup
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: 
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: CLI Building entry: ./src/index.tsx
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: CLI Using tsconfig: tsconfig.json
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: CLI tsup v8.0.2
[18:56:44.865] @testapp/ui:build: CLI Using tsup config: /vercel/path0/packages/ui/tsup.config.ts
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build: CLI Target: es6
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build: CJS Build start
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build: ESM Build start
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build:   npx update-browserslist-db@latest
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build:   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
[18:56:44.866] @testapp/ui:build: DTS Build start
[18:56:44.867] @testapp/ui:build: CJS dist/index.js  64.48 KB
[18:56:44.867] @testapp/ui:build: CJS dist/index.css 26.29 KB
[18:56:44.867] @testapp/ui:build: CJS ⚡️ Build success in 2259ms
[18:56:44.867] @testapp/ui:build: ESM dist/index.mjs 55.81 KB
[18:56:44.867] @testapp/ui:build: ESM dist/index.css 26.29 KB
[18:56:44.868] @testapp/ui:build: ESM ⚡️ Build success in 2259ms
[18:56:44.868] @testapp/ui:build: DTS ⚡️ Build success in 8157ms
[18:56:44.868] @testapp/ui:build: DTS dist/index.d.ts  12.20 KB
[18:56:44.868] @testapp/ui:build: DTS dist/index.d.mts 12.20 KB
[18:56:45.046] web:build: cache miss, executing f831f290b73cdf21
[18:56:45.578] web:build: 
[18:56:45.579] web:build: > web@1.0.0 build /vercel/path0/apps/web
[18:56:45.579] web:build: > next build
[18:56:45.580] web:build: 
[18:56:46.346] web:build: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[18:56:46.347] web:build: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[18:56:46.347] web:build: You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[18:56:46.348] web:build: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[18:56:46.348] web:build: 
[18:56:46.416] web:build:   ▲ Next.js 14.2.13
[18:56:46.417] web:build: 
[18:56:46.493] web:build:    Creating an optimized production build ...
[18:57:02.848] web:build: Failed to compile.
[18:57:02.848] web:build: 
[18:57:02.848] web:build: ./src/components/language-switcher.tsx
[18:57:02.848] web:build: Module not found: Can't resolve '@testapp/ui'
[18:57:02.848] web:build: 
[18:57:02.849] web:build: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[18:57:02.849] web:build: 
[18:57:02.849] web:build: Import trace for requested module:
[18:57:02.849] web:build: ./src/components/nav/main-nav.tsx
[18:57:02.849] web:build: 
[18:57:02.850] web:build: ./src/components/nav/main-nav.tsx
[18:57:02.850] web:build: Module not found: Can't resolve '@testapp/ui'
[18:57:02.850] web:build: 
[18:57:02.850] web:build: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[18:57:02.850] web:build: 
[18:57:02.851] web:build: ./src/components/nav/main-nav.tsx
[18:57:02.851] web:build: Module not found: Can't resolve '@testapp/utils'
[18:57:02.851] web:build: 
[18:57:02.851] web:build: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[18:57:02.851] web:build: 
[18:57:02.851] web:build: ./src/components/nav/nav-links.tsx
[18:57:02.852] web:build: Module not found: Can't resolve '@testapp/ui'
[18:57:02.852] web:build: 
[18:57:02.852] web:build: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[18:57:02.852] web:build: 
[18:57:02.852] web:build: Import trace for requested module:
[18:57:02.852] web:build: ./src/components/nav/main-nav.tsx
[18:57:02.852] web:build: 
[18:57:02.852] web:build: ./src/components/nav/navConfig.ts
[18:57:02.853] web:build: Module not found: Can't resolve '@testapp/ui'
[18:57:02.853] web:build: 
[18:57:02.853] web:build: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
[18:57:02.853] web:build: 
[18:57:02.853] web:build: Import trace for requested module:
[18:57:02.853] web:build: ./src/components/nav/nav-links.tsx
[18:57:02.854] web:build: ./src/components/nav/main-nav.tsx
[18:57:02.854] web:build: 
[18:57:02.855] web:build: 
[18:57:02.855] web:build: > Build failed because of webpack errors
[18:57:02.892] web:build:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
[18:57:02.907] web:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (/vercel/path0/apps/web) /pnpm9/node_modules/.bin/pnpm run build exited (1)
[18:57:02.908] web#build: command (/vercel/path0/apps/web) /pnpm9/node_modules/.bin/pnpm run build exited (1)
[18:57:02.909] 
[18:57:02.909]   Tasks:    2 successful, 3 total
[18:57:02.909]  Cached:    2 cached, 3 total
[18:57:02.910]    Time:    18.549s 
[18:57:02.910] Summary:    /vercel/path0/.turbo/runs/2ncZFg5cYVaEoR0k48a8OzFhUAi.json
[18:57:02.910]  Failed:    web#build
[18:57:02.910] 
[18:57:02.914]  ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)
[18:57:02.929] Error: Command "turbo run build" exited with 1
[18:57:03.457] 

